# dynamically populating a laravel drodpown

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4

i want to do a dynamically  populating laravel dropdown..i am trying to do this from past 3 days..but i can't..i don't know where i mistaken..every time i got different different errors..

now i got this error InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [RegisterController.getusertype] not found.

i want to fetch the values from table named as user_type..i have two columns in that table one is id,type...

```
public function getusertype() {
    $usertype = \DB::table('user_type')->pluck('type', 'id');
    //print_r($usertype);
    return \View('RegisterController.getusertype')->with('user_type', $usertype);

}
```

here is my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('Link Category') !!}<br />
                        {!! Form::select('usertype',
                             $usertype,
                                null,
                                ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
```

Can anyone help me..please..

Comment: Do you have this folder structure `resources/views/RegisterController` and inside a file `getusertype.blade.php` which you're trying to load in your controller?

Comment: no i have resources/view/registercontroller...getusertype is my method name

Comment: `\View('RegisterController.getusertype')` must be your blade template in `resources/views/`.